# T-SQL - Release Lock in Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking

Is it possible to release the lock of a certain table inside a transaction?

here is an example:

query window 1:

```
BEGIN TRAN
   UPDATE table_1 SET col_1 = '1' WHERE ID = 1

   -- loop update (this takes time)
   WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE col_1 = 'a')
   BEGIN
        UPDATE table_2 SET col_1 = 'b' WHERE col_1 = 'a' 
   END
COMMIT TRAN
```

query window 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE ID = 1
```

it possible to access table_1 while the transaction in window 1 is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "dirty read" with hint `NOLOCK`:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE ID = 1
```

Read more [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2470/understanding-the-sql-server-nolock-hint/).

Comment: thanks @Backs! but is there other way without modifying the query 2?

Comment: @Middleman no, because you have long transaction that locks table

Comment: i searched about read committed snapshot isolation, and i guess this is what i need https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation&ved=0ahUKEwjZkqv7uvnUAhXKUrwKHRFkCjgQFggmMAE&usg=AFQjCNGmPtAE6EP2cnRkFxFHhnOTC2PnEg